# Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Tags: package-management

```
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable.
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable.
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin.
```

Comment: Please update your answer and give more information, like when that error occurs (using `apt-get`?) and your Ubuntu version. Also post the results of the following commands: `which ldconfig` and `echo $PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `/sbin` to your $PATH as root

Check whether `/etc/sudoers` file has the correct PATH or not. By default `/etc/sudoers` should have the path mentioned below. If in case its not present go ahead and add /sbin.

Sample `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

Comment: _How do this? In terminal?

Comment: Open terminal and type `gksu gedit /etc/sudoers`

Comment: root@radica-K54C:~# /etc/sudoers
-bash: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied

Comment: If you already logged in as root use `vi /etc/sudoers` to edit the file

Comment: This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
"/etc/sudoers" [readonly] 26 lines, 574 characters

Comment: radica@radica-K54C:~$ sudo -s
[sudo] password for radica: 
root@radica-K54C:~# gksu gedit /etc/sudoers

(gksu:7121): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:7121): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:7121): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:7121): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

Comment: What now? In my status bar is red sign with white line, say this an error ocured,please run package manager from the right click menu or apt get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The eror massage was: Broken count>0. this usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependicies.

Comment: Yes the update manager failed to update the packages.

Comment: How to resolve?